# Order Recharts Bars

Tags: javascript, charts, recharts

I have such BarChart in Recharts:
[image]

Is there some way to sort bars inside every category?

Comment: This is a feature request. See: https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1184, there is a workaround on the last post but I haven't tested it.

Comment: You could try ordering the bars before rendering them using a loop as a workaround. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: thanks I think proposal of @adelriosantiago